# How to properly call another docker container via axios?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming

So I'm currently building a docker setup with a REST API and a separate frontend. My backend consists of Symfony 5.2.6 as REST API and my frontend is a simple Vue application.

When I try to call my API from the vue application via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, I get a "Connection refused" error. When I try to call the API via the external IP of my server, I run into CORS issues. This is my first setup like this, so I'm kind of at a loss.

This is my docker setup:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # VUE-JS Instance
  client:
    build: client
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  # SERVER
  php:
    build: php-fpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/:cached
      - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/var/logs:cached

  # WEBSERVER
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx:cached
```

So what is the correct way to establish the connection between those two containers?

Comment: What URL exactly are you calling?  Where are you calling it from (a `proxy_pass` directive in the `nginx` container, code running in your Vue application in the browser, another host entirely)?

Comment: It an axios POST-request I perform on a form submit in my Vue Component. And I basically just call .e.g. `127.0.0.1/api/user/login`.

Answer (score -1):

The client app runs on port 8080 but nginx on 80 is a different URL and it should be a CORS error.
To avoid it, in the PHP app, you have to add response header:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080` or
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.
Another solution is to configure all in one domain on this same port.